# Keyboard forensics? (Physical layer)

Tags: encryption, forensics

If I had a strong bootup password that **I typed into my keyboard daily** to mount my "encrypted system partition"...

Q1) Would it be possible for an adversary to find out my password by analyzing my keyboard?  For example, by breaking it down and finding what characters are used frequently? (Ex: if I typed in my pass every day for like months/years)

Q2) If i bought a new keyboard or laptop, and only typed my password  infrequently (2-3 times) and I rarely used my laptop to type anything else, is it still possible? Or very unlikely?

Q3) If I bought a brand new keyboard, and typed it in once or twice, and then typed in fake keys after I hit "enter".. would this also be very unlikely?
(Ex: if the pass is 12345.. i would type in 12345 ENTER then 67890qweurhdghkjnxxvbmbvxjkbvkjb     etc etc)

**EDIT**

Okay thanks for all the replies. I feel like I got a grasp on how this works, but just to clarify....

In other words, If I typed in a password every morning, and throughout the day I typed random letters/numbers, there is no way to distinguish... "THESE specific keys (AKA my password), are typed together at THIS particular time"  while the rest of the keys typed are randomly throughout the day etc.........

OR If I typed in a password every morning for lets say a month.... and rarely typed any other keys except ENTER and using my mouse...........And then a year later I started typing like normal,

**There would be no way to distinguish, THESE KEYS (aka my password) were typed a lot in THIS YEAR..... and now every other key have been typed for the last month...........?**

**In other words,** 
1. I can type 12345 every day for a month and NEVER TOUCH any other key.
2. and 1 year later, I can type regularly most letters/numbers,

**There would be no way to distinguish WHEN certain keys or letters were typed?** (Ex: There would be no way to distinguish 12345 were typed uniquely at a different timeframe than the rest of the keys)

Does that make sense? (Sorry its a little confusing but I am not the most articulate communicator!)

Comment: This depends on how often you type the password compared to other keys. Assuming they have access to your keyboard (and are not remotely spying on you _as_ you enter it), it is unlikely that they would get enough information to retrieve your password. I am not aware of any specific research on that subject, though. Not for keyboards at least.

Comment: This feels more like a question about statistics than one about information security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: No, unless your password is something strange like pressing keys that are normally rarely used. Q3: Yes it would help, entering fake passwords would spread the finger prints and other wear around. I would imagine that someone could clean your keyboard and then look for finger prints after you entered your password. This applies to your second question since a new keyboard is likely clean. They could also figure out how to get some kind of marker on your fingers and then have you enter your password. Or maybe your hands happened to be sweaty and salty and it left a trace on the keys. The best that they could do in any case is to find out what letters are in your password but they would have no idea what order they are in.

Answer (score 4):

No, unless you used letters that are not common and entered your password a LOT.  The most commonly used letters of the English language are EATONDSR, I believe.  So if your password contained any of those letters, it would be impossible to know whether you used them in your password or in standard keyboarding.  If, however, you used JXQZ in your password, those would have abnormal wear on them relative to someone who didn't use them.  That might give an adversary a starting point.  However, you would (again) need to enter your password a LOT.

Keep in mind that you generally enter your password once per session.  If you type e-mails, documents, or do other text work the noise to signal ratio would be very high.  The keys used for standard text work would wear LONG before the keys used for your password would.  Even typing your question here created a high signal-noise ration in terms of wear on the keyboard.  Because of that, it would take someone very dedicated to do this.  It would be a lot easier to  attack the machine a different way than to analyze your keyboard.

Edit:  Even if you only entered your password on the keyboard and then used only the mouse, the attacker would only be able to find the keys that get pressed.  They would have no idea of the length of the password and, if you used the shift key once in the sequence, no idea of where you used the shift key.  That reduces the number of possibilities from infinity to a pretty huge universe.  They'd still need to try every possible combination of those letters, out to the max possible length.

Comment: Even if an attacker had the _precise_ usage ratios of each and every key in relation to the others, it would still be exceptionally difficult to speed up password cracking by any measurable amount. It's even less likely given that you would not have exact usage ratios for each key, but a very rough approximation based on wear.

Answer (score 1):

Some security keypads are susceptible to this sort of attack given that the only thing ever typed on it is a given password. If not changed regularly the numbers printed on the keys will wear over time, and once you know which ones are involved, it's just a matter of trying every combination of those keys until you're in.

There are also theoretical attacks that involve measuring keystrokes using sound, so someone listening in on you typing it in could theoretically try to divine your password that way.

In reality though, the easiest way to get your password would be to monitor your comings and goings, break into your house when you're not there, replace your keyboard with an identical one containing an embedded keylogger, then break in again later to retrieve it and restore the original. Then simply download the keystroke records and analyze them.

Then, for whatever you're up to, they'd get a search warrant, confiscate your stuff and read your drive like an open book, claiming that they cracked the password on their own.